# Need help in datetime SQL Syntax

Tags: mysql, vb.net

In TableAdapter Configuration Wizard, I am having an issue with my SQL statement.

I wanted to filter CreatedDate for that particular Year based on the current date. So I use the Year() function, but when executed, it prompts an error message.

[image: Error Message Prompt]

Below is my SQL statement.

```
SELECT cff.CFNo, cff.RegionalOffice, cffitemstatus.Reason
FROM cff, cffitemstatus
WHERE cff.RecordNo = cffitemstatus.RecordNo 
  AND (cff.CreatedDate = `YEAR`(CURDATE()))
ORDER BY cff.RegionalOffice, cffitemstatus.Reason
```

Need guide and advise on this issue.

Comment: You have used backticks around the `YEAR` function name, just remove them and all should be well syntactically. `YEAR(CURDATE())` I would expect you would also need the YEAR function applied to `cff.CreatedDate` as well though `AND YEAR(cff.CreatedDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Then, one method to do what you want is to use `YEAR()` on both dates:

```
SELECT cff.CFNo, cff.RegionalOffice, cffitemstatus.Reason
FROM cff JOIN
     cffitemstatus
     ON cff.RecordNo = cffitemstatus.RecordNo 
WHERE YEAR(cff.CreatedDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
ORDER BY cff.RegionalOffice, cffitemstatus.Reason;
```